# GUI service manager for OS X?

Tags: macos, launchd, services

I am looking for a GUI application, with in icon on the top bar, that can be used to start and stop different services on OS X.

These do not have to be real OS X (launchd) services/daemons, it is enough for me to be able to define them, with a name, a start and a stop script.

Mainly I want to use it for development to manage things like tomcat, nginx, postgresql... which are not usually started.

Comment: I'm not aware of such an app, but it sounds like you're probably quite capable of writing small AppleScripts that would start and stop these services you're interested in. If so, the solution might just be to do that, and access those scripts via the existing Script menu on the top bar. (Which you may need to turn on via the AppleScript Editor app preferences, if you don't already see it.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd rather have this a comment, but for some reason I can only post answers.

Have a look at LaunchControl: http://www.soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/. While it does not offer a menu item to start/stop services it provides a list of all available launchd jobs, their current status and a way to start/stop them with the click of a button.

**EDIT**

LaunchControl now does offer a menu item for controlling selected jobs:

[image]

Comment: This is a valid answer, no reason to hide it in a comment. Regarding comments, you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: LaunchControl is the best tool for this by a wide margin. I used to love Peter's Lingon but this has a **much** nicer interface. Same price, too.

Answer (score 2):

You may also give a try to [Lingon X](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) . You can use it to start and stop services, schedule them, etc. It is basically a GUI to `launchctl`, you do not have to deal with those pesky plists directly. It is not free (costs $10), there's a demo version.

Note that the only important information in this answer is the name of the app and the URL at which you can find it -- the rest should be straightforward both for the original poster and other people looking for a similar program. However, I was warned by some higher entity that one-liner answers are not sufficient. Trying to be a good StackExchange citizen, I added a bit more detailed description of the tool. :-)